# Should I be concerned about the Linux.Darlloz worm?

Tags: malware

As an Ubuntu user, any tips on how Linux.Darlloz could affect Ubuntu and ways to prevent it?

Comment: https://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2013-112710-1612-99

Comment: I don't see any reason to downvote this question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you don't have PHP-cgi installed or if you upgrade it recently. Nothing.

> Linux.Darlloz is a worm that spreads to vulnerable systems by exploiting the PHP 'php-cgi'.

Ubuntu already **release fixes to prevent spread more than a year ago**:

- http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2012/CVE-2012-1823.html
- http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2012/CVE-2012-2311.html
- http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2012/CVE-2012-2335.html
- http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2012/CVE-2012-2336.html

Comment: only server that have webserver + php (with php-cgi installed) running, will be affected.   this does not affect he normal Linux client machine if they dont have webserver and php-cgi in use, or have php-cgi installed,but no webserver.